# strange C macro syntax (#var)

Tags: c, syntax, macros

What does the # symbol mean when used as a variable prefix in a #define macro?

For example,

```
#define my_setopt(x,y,z) _my_setopt(x, 0, config, #y, y, z)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the [Stringizing Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7e3a913x%28VS.80%29.aspx), which converts macro parameters to string literals.

So in your example:

```
my_setopt(1, 2, 3)
```

would expand to:

```
_my_setopt(1, 0, config, "2", 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

`#` quotes the expression. For example:

```
#define SHOW(BAR) printf("%s is %d\n", #BAR , BAR)
SHOW(3+5);  // prints: 3+5 is 8
```